# Getting a user entered value and displaying it within other pre-selected text. Java

Tags: java, printing, io, output, bluej

So we just started java in my intro to computer science class in college. We have to modify the code to display " If the magnitude on the Richter scale is (user entered value)" "(answer determined by user input" I am completely new to programming so i am having trouble with this.So basically it need to grab the number the user enters in a dialogue box and print it out between these two sections of text. We use BlueJ to code. We run the program and it opens the answer in terminal.

This is the code that needs edited:

```
/**
* Write a description of class Earthquake here.
*
* A class that describes the effects of an earthquake.
* @author Michael Gerhart
* @version Version 1.0, 4/22/2013
*/
public class Earthquake
{
// instance variables
private double richter;
/**
* Constructor for objects of class Earthquake
* @param magnitude the magnitude on the Richter scale
*/
public Earthquake(double magnitude)
{
// initialise instance variable richter
richter = magnitude;
}
/**
* Gets a description of the effect of the earthquake.
*
* @return the description of the effect
*/
enter code here`public String getDescription(double magnitude)
{
String r;
if (richter >= 8.0)
r = "Most structures fall";
else if (richter >= 7.0)
r = "Many buildings destroyed";
else if (richter >= 6.0)
r = "Many buildings considerably damaged; "
+ "some collapse";
else if (richter >= 4.5)
r = "Damage to poorly constructed buildings";
else if (richter >= 3.5)
r = "Felt by many people, no destruction";
else if (richter >= 0)
r = "Generally not felt by people";
else
r = "Negative numbers are not valid";
return r;
}
}
```

This is the code that runs the program:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
* Write a description of class EarthquakeTest here.
*
* A class to test the Earthquake class.
*
* @author Michael Gerhart
* @version 4/22/2013
*/
public class EarthquakeTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a magnitude on the Richter scale:");
double magnitude = Double.parseDouble(input);
Earthquake quake = new Earthquake(magnitude);
String quakeDamage = quake.getDescription(magnitude);
System.out.println(quakeDamage);
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard for me to understand what you're asking, but if I understand correctly, you need to display something like, "If the magnitude is 3.8, Felt by many people, no destruction."  In that case, you're almost there; you just need to use String concatenation.  It's like smushing two Strings together to make one String.

quakeDamage already holds the second block of text (in this case, "Felt by many people, no destruction").  You need another String variable to hold the final result.  Try something like this:

```
String result = "If the magnitude is " + magnitude + ", " + quakeDamage;
System.out.println(result);
```

That should print out the entire text.

(By the way, after you experiment with that a little bit, you may want to edit the text defined in the Earthquake class to make it look a little prettier.  Notice the capital letter in "Felt" will show up in the middle of the sentence.)